# Delete duplicate max row in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I want to delete duplicate rows in SQL. My query can delete duplicate rows for `RN > 1`, but I want to delete `max(RN)` instead:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3]
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [col1], [col2] ORDER BY [col1], [col2])
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

[image: Example data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the partition to the reverse of the current order, then delete just records with the first row number:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3]
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [col1], [col2] ORDER BY [col1] DESC, [col2] DESC)
    FROM dbo.Table1
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1;
```